# How to run angular 2 application by angular cli

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am trying to create a application using angular 2. I got a sample project folder from github.when I run the application I am getting "Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found" error message. How to resolve this issue?

Package.json

```
{
"name": "demo-app",
"version": "1.0.0",
"author": "Aravind",
"description": "set up files for the first Demo App",
"scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lint": "tslint ./app/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "typings": "typings",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
},
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "tslint": "^3.7.4",
    "typescript": "^2.0.2",
    "typings": "^1.0.4"
},
"repository": {}
 }
```

Comment: use ng serve command to run

Comment: We are in 2018 now, it's pretty strange to start an Angular 2 application since Angular 6 is out :). The project your forked seem to be outdated :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Angular CLI is v6+, and your Angular App is v2. There must be `angular-cli.json` file in your project. In the latest version of CLI, after v6, config. file is renamed with `angular.json` with slighter changes. Please create `angular.json` file and update it accordingly, if this is the case.

Otherwise, just create a new project using `ng new <appName>` and hit `ng serve`. As Angular CLI is the latest installed in your machine, so it will create `angular.json` by default.

Learn more about Angular CLI commands [here](https://cli.angular.io/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes looks like your Angular project is outdated, the newest Angular uses `angular.json`, not `angular-cli.json`.

Either ask the creator to update it or do it yourself by following this: https://update.angular.io/